# VML Button is not align with text

Tags: html, css, outlook, vml

I have specific requirement, where button is next to p tag. As Button needs to be rounded, I had to use vml tags. here is my code and image how it looks in outlook. button is slightly moved top and not in the middle.

```html
<table>
   <tr>
      <td>
         <p style="font-size:11pt;font-family:Arial,Verdana,sans-serif;margin-left:20px; line-height:1.2">
            So you don’t miss out, during EADV we’d like to send you daily reminders. If you’d prefer not to receive these please let us know
            <!--[if mso]>
            <span style="text-decoration:none;display:inline-block;color:white;background-color:#1A55A6;border-radius:25px;-webkit-border-radius:25px;-moz-border-radius:25px;width:auto; width:auto;padding-top:5px;padding-bottom:5px;font-family:'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans', Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;text-align:center;mso-border-alt:none;word-break:keep-all;">
               <v:roundrect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" href="https://cloud.info.ucb.com/eadv?accountId=%%=v(@accountId)=%%&eventId=%%=v(@eventId)=%%&optIn=%%=v(@optIn)=%%" style="height:20pt;width:50pt;v-text-anchor:middle;"  arcsize="45%" strokeweight="0.75pt" inset="0,0,0,0" strokecolor="#1A55A6" fillcolor="#1A55A6">
                  <v:textbox inset="0,0,0,0">
         <center style="color:white; font-family:Verdana, sans-serif; font-size:15px">
         <![endif]-->
         <a alias="" class="buttonstyles" conversion="false" data-linkto="http://" href="https://cloud.info.ucb.com/eadv?accountId=%%=v(@accountId)=%%&eventId=%%=v(@eventId)=%%&optIn=%%=v(@optIn)=%%" target="_blank" title="ics1"><span style="padding-left:5px;padding-right:5px;font-size:14px;display:inline-block;letter-spacing:normal;color:white"><span dir="ltr" style="mso-line-height-alt: 24px;">
         <strong>here</strong>
         </span></span></a></span>
         <!--[if mso]></v:textbox></v:roundrect><![endif]--> 
         </p>
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Button image, click here
[image]